# Reference to XPath - is it possible?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium to automate a browser task through a Python script.

There is a text-box in my browser that I need to fill with info, but the XPath is formatted as below:

> //*[@id="NameInputId14514271346457986"]

The problem is that: everytime the number before the Id (14514271346457986) changes. Is there a way to refer to this XPath something like:

> //*[@id.start-with="NameInputId"]

Sorry if it is a dumb question - I started to using Selenium this week and I couldn't find this info on documentation.

Comment: Without seeing a representative example of the HTML you are dealing with it is difficult for us to give you the correct XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `xpath` like `//*[contains(@id,"NameInputId")]` but I guess this possibly will not be an unique locator. In this case the `xpath` should be more complex to contain additional attributes or some parent element

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether the first 9 characters of the `@id` value equals "NameInput", for an **XPath 1.0** expression:

```
//*[fn:substring(@id, 1, 9) = "NameInput"]
```

With **XPath 2.0** (and greater) you could use the [`starts-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-starts-with) function:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, "NameInput")]
```

Comment: @z0rd : Based on your Id structure `starts-with()` is the best option to identify the element.

Answer (score 1):

you can use xpath like this

```
//*[@id[contains(.,'NameInputId')]]
```